# Angular - ngx-mask - convert mask to number

Tags: angular, input, converters, ngx-mask

I am using ngx-mask like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
                                       id="price" 
                                       name="price" 
                                       [(ngModel)]="product.maskPrice" 
                                      
                                        mask="separator.2" 
                                       thousandSeparator="." 
                                       >
```

So I have to transform this input to number, like: 1234,56 to 1234.56, because my endpoint excepts a number type for the price.

Here is my code:

`product.price = +product.maskPrice!.replace(",",'.');`

How is the best way to do this?

My solution use this interface to keep mask and number price information:

```
export interface Product {
    id ?: number;
    name ?: string;
    
    price ?: number;
    maskPrice ?: string;
    
    newProduct ?: boolean;
}
```

Any suggestion to improve this code?
Thanks!